# How do I do the circular wipe movement on Photoshop, Premiere or AfterEffects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-after-effects

Watch this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yAJn3CD2atU

See the circular movement "pizza-style" that rotates anti-clockwise? How do I do that, filling the whole screen, using Photoshop, Premiere or After Effects?

The screen starts all white, every second the dark gray wipe rotates the screen. At the beginning of each second the screen is white again.

thanks

Comment: Can you show/tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: nothing because I don't know how to start.

Comment: Damn and i was just about to answer your other question and then you go and [delete it](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116284/trying-to-plot-a-sine-wave-using-javascript-in-a-photoshop-script)

Comment: sorry about that. I have undeleted it... accept my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as shown below

1. make two boxes with the same color and with none stroke.
2. Rotate box 180 degree until hiding box 1
3. at this point rotate box 1 while box 2 go to its original place as a mask. lets say its box 3 that mask box 1 while rotation.

[image]

Comment: I took I understood the part that box 2 rotates from 0 to 180 degrees, using as a pivot the screen center. Then I think I understand the remaining part. Thanks!